# How can I use xmltype to extract the value of a specific tag of an XML document in the case that I have more tag having the same name?

Tags: xml, oracle, xml-parsing, clob, xmltype

I am pretty new in Oracle and I have the following problem extracting a specific field from an XML document that is inside a **CLOG** field of a table on the DB.

So, into my XML I have this strutcure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<in:Invoice xmlns:in="urn:oasis:.....">

    <cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
        <cac:Party>
            .............................
            .............................

            /* FIRST cac:PartyLegalEntity that contains a cbc:CompanyID element */
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:CompanyID>VALUE-1</cbc:CompanyID>
                .............................
                .............................
                </cac:RegistrationAddress>
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>

            /* SECOND cac:PartyLegalEntity that contains a cbc:CompanyID element */
            <cac:PartyLegalEntity>
                <cbc:CompanyID>VALUE-2</cbc:CompanyID>
                .............................
                .............................
            </cac:PartyLegalEntity>

        </cac:Party>
    </cac:AccountingSupplierParty>
</in:Invoice>
```

So now into a query I have to obtain the the string value contained into the **cbc:CompanyID** element inside the **SECOND cac:PartyLegalEntity** element (the **VALUE-2** value).

I done in this way:

```
xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT (
      '//cac:AccountingSupplierParty//cac:PartyLegalEntity/cbc:CompanyID/text()')
      .getStringVal() AS PIVA_MITTENTE
```

But doing in this way the result of my query is a row wiht the column **PIVA_MITTENTE** that contains the value **VALUE-1VALUE-2** instedad the **VALUE-2** that is wath I want.

I think that problem is that the container tag () is the same for both the  tag (that have the same name) and into these tag I extract the value of the same tag .

I can't modify the XML so can I specify somehow that I want the value of the  tag that is inside the **SECOND**  tag into my XML? How can I do it and solve this issue?

**EDIT 1:**

My original query is this one:

```
SELECT

xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT (
      '//cac:AccountingSupplierParty//cac:PartyLegalEntity/cac:RegistrationAddress/cbc:PostalZone/text()')
      .getStringVal() AS CAP_MITTENTE,  

xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT (
      '//cac:AccountingSupplierParty//cac:PartyLegalEntity/cbc:CompanyID/text()')
      .getStringVal() AS PIVA_MITTENTE

FROM coda_tx c, documenti_tx d
WHERE   C.FK_TIPO_DOC = 99
        AND C.FK_STATO = 1
        AND C.FK_PIVA_MITTENTE = '11111111'
        AND C.PK_CODA = D.PFK_CODA
        AND C.CANALE='STA';
```

The second **xmltype (d.documento).EXTRACT** is the one that give me the described issue.

How can I integrate the use of the **XMLTABLE** into my previous query?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [XMLTable](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions253.htm) function. Your query will look something like this:

Here is example from the doc:

```
SELECT warehouse_name warehouse,
   warehouse2."Water", warehouse2."Rail"
   FROM warehouses,
   XMLTABLE('/Warehouse'
      PASSING warehouses.warehouse_spec
      COLUMNS 
         "Water" varchar2(6) PATH '/Warehouse/WaterAccess',
         "Rail" varchar2(6) PATH '/Warehouse/RailAccess') 
      warehouse2;
```

I believe you can figure out how to pass your XPATH.

UPDATE:
In your case it will be look something like that:

```
SELECT d.*,
       x.company_id
 FROM d,
      XMLTABLE('//cac:AccountingSupplierParty//cac:PartyLegalEntity/'
              PASSING d.documento 
              COLUMNS company_id varchar2(6) PATH '/cbc:CompanyID'
              ) x;
```

Comment: mmm I am absolutly new in this field. can you show me a code snippet related to my specific case?

Comment: Yes, Can you please give me your table definition?

Comment: what table do you need?. The previous query is done on a CLOB field (that contains an XML) of a table. So I think that the query is done on the XML by XPATH or something like this. What am I missing?

Comment: mmm when I try to integrate into my query don't works. I edited my original post putting in it the entire query in wich I have to integrate the XMLTABLE statment